# ASP.NET UpdatePanel and Button Not Doing Full and/or Partial Postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, modal-dialog, updatepanel, partial-postback

I know that this is a common question, but I'm sure my code is sufficiently correct and it's not working for me.  I have a modal window which, when up, presents an UpdatePanel which has several Panel's within it, and on one of them, is a plain button.  Clicking the button isn't providing ANY postback (partial or full).  Ideally, I'd like to just do a partial postback, but I can't get any type of postback now.  Here's some of my code:

For the ScriptManager:

```
myScriptManager.ID = "ScriptManager1"
myScriptManager.EnablePageMethods = True    
myScriptManager.EnablePartialRendering = True
MainForm.Controls.Add(myScriptManager)
```

For the UpdatePanel:

```
With BeginBroadcastPanel
    .ID = "BeginBroadcastPanel"
    .Attributes.Add("style", "display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-contents:center;align-items:center;")
    '.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional
    '.ChildrenAsTriggers = True
End With
```

For the Button:

```
With lblBroadcastPanelLoginButton   
    .ID = "lblBroadcastPanelLoginButton"
    .Text = "LOG IN"
    .Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight:bold;margin:20px;width:50%;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;font-size:20pt;background:lightgray;border-radius:4px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;border:0px solid darkgray;")
    '.Attributes.Add("onclick", "__doPostBack('<%=BeginBroadcastPanel.ClientID %>', null);")
    'Dim t As New AsyncPostBackTrigger
    't.ControlID = lblBroadcastPanelLoginButton.ClientID
    't.EventName = "Click"
    'BeginBroadcastPanel.Triggers.Add(t)
End With
```

As you can see, I've tried many different solutions, such as setting the UpdateMode, ChildrenAsTriggers, adding an AsyncPostBackTrigger.  Only the Javascript kind of worked, but it'll only do a full postback (and it's my understanding that Javascript shouldn't be necessary to do the partial postback).  To check if a partial postback is happening, I have a field which displays the current datetime.  Any ideas what's wrong here?

EDIT:  I discovered that a postback is occurring, but the textfield that was showing the datetime was not updating.  If I display the datetime in a label, it shows that the datetime is increasing.  Oddly enough, both IsPostBack and IsInAsyncPostBack evaluate to True with each postback.  Also odd, if I increment a public integer (see example below), it only fires on the first postback but not any subsequent postbacks.

```
Public test As Integer
Public dttm As DateTime = DateTime.Now

Dim b As New Button
With b
    test = test + 1 
    .Text = dttm.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") & " - " & test.ToString & " - " & Page.IsPostBack
End With
BeginBroadcastPanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(b)
```

In the code above, I'm showing both the dttm and test variables on the button.  The dttm is incrementing up, but the test variable is not.  Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: the button was missing a Click handler.  After adding an AddHandler, got everything going.